# Can you do an "if statement" within an html tag?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

I have an Asp.net Core MVC application. In my _Layout.cshtml page I'm trying to create a link on the nav bar to create a new ad. I would like that if the user is logged in, they get taken to the page where they can create a new ad. Otherwise, if they are not logged in, they should be taken to a login page.
The question basically is, can you use the @ sign within an html tag to type some c#. Here's what I want to do, but it's not valid code.

```
           <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" 
                     @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                     {
                          asp-action="NewAd"
                     }
                     else
                     {
                          asp-action="LogIn"
                     }>
                  New Ad</a>
           </li>
```

Even better would be to do the shorthand version of an if statment somehow, ie:

```
(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? asp-action="NewAd" : asp-action="LogIn")
```

Is there any way to achieve this without duplicating the tag inside an if/else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot nest razor views inside html tags.
But, I can see based on your requirements you need to redirect the user to the login page if he hasn't registered yet. For that you can:

```
@if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
     //if user is not authenticated return the page with 
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LogIn"></a>
}
else{
     //if user is authenticated return the page with 
     <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="NewAd"></a>
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did in the end. I was hoping for a way to shorten the logic, but it seems like this is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the code in a script tag.

```
  <script>if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                 {
                      asp-action="NewAd"
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      asp-action="LogIn"
                 } </script>
```